# Play! Framework controller returns EMPTY RESPONSE after adding reactivemongo plugin

Tags: mongodb, scala, web, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I am quite new to reactivemongo and Play framework. I was working on a Play  application when time to add MongoDB connection came. I decided to go with reactiveMongo and made everything according to the tutorial here:
https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app

The problem that I am experiencing is that after I added the plugin and configured it I started receiving empty responses(ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) from the application. As soon as I remove the plugin and it's initialization I start receving again my proper web app responses with HTML text.

Here is the build file:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "webapp"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10-SNAPSHOT"
  )
  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    resolvers += "Sonatype Snapshots" at       "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
  )
}
```

plugins config file is typical, just one line:

```
400:play.modules.reactivemongo.ReactiveMongoPlugin
```

Here is my console output during the start and page opening:

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] application - ReactiveMongoPlugin starting...
[info] application - ReactiveMongoPlugin successfully started with db 'users'! Servers:
                [localhost:27017]
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[WARN] [08/16/2013 23:12:28.922] [New I/O worker #1] [EventStream(akka://play)]     [akka.event-handlers] config is deprecat
ed, use [akka.loggers]
```

What could be the cause of such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bunch of iterations I figured out this was a version mismatch problem, binary incompatility. Always make sure you check what version was used to compile every library, as sometimes it doesn't display an error about being binary incompatible.